# How to show seperate DataTables and Text for each map in json list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show json data with `DataTable()` but i get error:

`type '(dynamic) => Column?' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => DataTable' of 'f'`

My question is how i can resolve the error but most importantly  how can i iterate through the list `block_data` and then for each map show `header` and `title` in seperate `DataTable()` where they are on top of eachother and each`description` below each `DataTable()`?

This is the view where i call the method `setTestData()` which awaits the `Future` `AppContent().getAppContent()` and then set the data to the field `testObject` and i also initialize `setTestData()` in current state. I can then use `testObject` to acces the json data.

My goal is to show EACH map from list `block_data` as SEPERATE `DataTable` for my usecase i have to do that. The reason why i want to this like that is because i also want to show the `description` below `DataTable` as a seperate `Text()` widget because it can be too long and in my usecase it has to be below the table

I now have this `AppView` statefull widget which i want to use to show each `DataTable()` seperatly based on each map from list `block_data`. I am not sure if i do it the right way but right now i get the error so it is more unclear if i can even achieve my goal this way:

```
class AppView extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppViewState createState() => _AppViewState();
}

class _AppViewState extends State<AppView> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  late Map<String, dynamic> testObject = {};

  setTestData() async {
    await AppContent()
        .getAppContent()
        .then((result) => setState(() => testObject = result));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    setTestData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.menu,
                    size: 40), // change this size and style
                onPressed: () => _scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer(),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    FutureBuilder(
                        future: AppContent().getAppContent(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            debugPrint(testObject["data"]["views"]["books"][0]
                                    ["block_data"]
                                .toString());
                            return Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                    child: (testObject["data"]["views"]["books"]
                                            [0]["block_data"])
                                        .map<DataTable>((object) {
                                      if (object.containsKey("header")) {
                                        return Column(
                                          children: [
                                            DataTable(
                                              horizontalMargin: 0,
                                              columnSpacing: 75,
                                              columns: <DataColumn>[
                                                DataColumn(
                                                  label: Container(
                                                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                                      child: Text(
                                                        object["header"]
                                                            .toString(),
                                                      )),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                              rows: <DataRow>[
                                                DataRow(
                                                  cells: <DataCell>[
                                                    DataCell(Text(
                                                      object['title']
                                                          .toString(),
                                                    DataCell(Text(object['date'].toString()
                                                    ))
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            Text(object["description"]
                                                .toString())
                                          ],
                                        );
                                      } else {
                                        Container();
                                      }
                                    }).toList()),
                                Text(
                                    "This is another placeholder for another list")
                              ],
                            );
                          } else {
                            return CircularProgressIndicator();
                          }
                        }),
                  ],
                );
              }, childCount: 1),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the method `AppContent().getAppContent()` which grabs the json:

```
class AppContent {
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getAppContent() async {
    String jsonData = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/test.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData);
    return data;
  }


}
```

And this the json which i call:

```
{
  "data": {


    "views": {
      "books": [

        {
          "block_type": "list",
          "block_data": [
            {
              "header": "FAQ",
              "long_text_type": "description",
              "title": "Service fees",
              "date": "19-01-2022",
              "description": "Information about fees and surcharges."

            },
            {
              "header": "FAQ",
              "long_text_type": "description",
              "title": "Returns & Refunds",
              "date": "03-06-2022",
              "description": "How to return products and recieve refunds.."

            }

          ]
    }
  }
}
}
```

**Edit**

I want it to look like the picture below where i have a datable for and description below that. But i want it for each map in list `block_data` and so i want to show the next map below the description and then show basicly `DataTable` -> `description` -> `DataTable` -> `description`. But i want to iterate through list `block_data` and generate `DataTable` and `Text` based on maps inside list which could be more than just two maps

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues here.

1. Your JSON has an error (probably a copy/paste error, but double-check it).
   Instead of
   `"block_data": "block_data": [` you should have `"block_data": [`.
   Moreover, a bracket is missing at the end of your JSON file (but again, I guess that it's because you only showed a part of your file to help us investigate your problem)
2. The error you wrote in your question is related to your `.map<DataTable>((object) {`
   When using the `.map`, the Object you specify is the return type of your mapping. In your case you're returning a `Column` and not a `DataTable`.
   If you want to iterate on a list, and create a list of Widgets in return, you can use this instead:
   `.map<Widget>((object) {`
3. Finally, **and the most important point of this answer** : you're having problems here because you're not converting your JSON file in a Dart Object you can easily manipulate.
   You can simply paste your JSON file on this website : https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/  and retrieve the code to add to your project.
   Then, you'll have a model with a fromJson and a toJson methods.
   Thanks to those methods, you'll be able to create Dart Objects from your JSON values, and thus to create your Widgets easily.

With this answer, you should be good to go. Add a comment if I need to add more details.

Comment: I have now covered point 1 and 2. Point 3 is not possible because in my usecase i need to avoid that. The keys from the json can change in the api

Comment: Is there another way to resolve point 3?

Comment: I still get the error when i added `<Widget>`

Comment: Reading that the keys from the JSON provided by your API aren't reliable sounds super scary. You should avoid this kind of behavior ! Having "optional" keys which could be null is okay, but having a model that could change is not, especially if you have to rely on the values instead..

Comment: But that is how my usecase works. In my usecase a user logs in to my app and then based on the user they see different information like what type of blocks there are like title, text, subtitle, table, different graphs etc. How this info is presented varies and only the keys which show `menu` and `views` are constant. Inside `menu` you have navigations to different `views` and inside these `views` you have the different blocks which can be sorted differently and also the key names could vary inside `views` and `menu`